# How to use VRView in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, virtual

VRview is not working and doesn't show me the 360 image. I am coding in Angular 1 app and trying to show 360 image. I tried photosphere viewer and now vrviewer but unable to understand regarding how to write the code in angular. Kindly assist

```
angular.module("MyControllers", [])
.controller("VR", function ($window) {
var onVrViewLoad = function() {
            var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                img: 'img/virtualTour.jpg',
                is_stereo: false
            });
        }
        $window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)


 })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google VR](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web) docs

> To use VR View, include the Google-provided `vrview.min.js` script
>   within your HTML:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
> ```

**Video View**

Your controller should be as follows. Instantiate the VR View as soon as the page loads which should be listening to the `load` event.

```
angular.module('VRApp', [])
  .controller('VRController', function($window) {
    var onVrViewLoad = function() {
      var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        video: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/congo_2048.mp4',
        is_stereo: true,
      });
    };
    $window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);
  });
```

Check out my [Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/5YHXo8AvgCGbLBBO?preview) for live demonstration.

---

**Image View**

I've tested it in IE 11 and it worked fine. Tried the below code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('VRController', function($scope, $window) {
    var onVrViewLoad = function() {
      var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        width: '60%',
        height: '60%',
        img: 'http://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&is_stereo=true',
        is_stereo: true,
      });
    };
    $window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);
  });
```

**Output in IE 11**

[image: Image View]

Comment: Great, Thanks Pavan for the efforts. How to do it for 360 image? Second, I tried to test it on IE, but it doesn't work there

Comment: I figured it for 360 image, but unable to make it work on IE 11

Comment: @Monsters I've edited my answer with 360 *Image View* and it was tested in IE 11 which worked fine. Also, I changed the order of load event which should be called right after we set the `vrView`

Comment: I tried accessing the plunkr from IE 11, it keeps loading forever. Also, I tried the same code in my app, it works in chrome but doesn't show anything in IE 11 :/

Comment: Do you see any errors on the IE11 console, developer tools? @Monsters

Comment: @Monsters Try clearing cache on the IE 11 browser and try reloading the app.

Comment: No I didn't find any errors. For plunker, it just keeps loading forever and never opens anything